# Declaring Blueprint in init file

Tags: python, flask

I have a blueprint, let's called it dashboard. Assume I have the following structure:

```
/application
  app.py
  /dashboard
    __init__.py
    controller1.py
    controller2.py
    /templates
```

Right now, I only have 1 controller hence the blueprint is declared there. If I want to add another controller, it would be best to declare the blueprint in the init file in /dashboard. Doing so however, I cannot import the dashboard blueprint from app.py.

Is there a workaround for this? Or does this indicate a smell in my blueprint structure?

**Edit**

Here is the error that I get (and the steps):

In application/dashboard/__init__.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint
dashboard = Blueprint('dashboard', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')
```

In application/dashboard/controller.py:

```
from application.dashboard import dashboard
# @dashboard.routes here
```

In application/__init__.py:

```
from application.dashboard import dashboard
app.register_blueprint(dashboard)
```

When I try to access any route in the dashboard blueprint, I get a 404 Not found:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Comment: *I cannot import the dashboard blueprint from app.py* Uhm, yes you can. What error do you get when you do this?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Please see edit. I posted the steps to reproduce as well as the error I see when I load the page.

Comment: You do need to import the other modules in the `dashboard/` package so that they can register the routes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oops that was it. Thanks!

Comment: @darksky - Can you please elaborate on what you finally did to get this working. I have the exact same problem and am unable to resolve it. It seems that the blueprint instance created in __init__.py is not visible to the controllers.

Comment: @AnuragJoshi Unfortunately, I do not remember. That was 4 years ago.

Comment: If anyone comes here from the future... the solution I found was to import the routes in `controller1.py` and `controller2.py` inside `application/dashboard/__init__.py`, i.e. add `from .controller1 import *; from .controller2 import *` to `__init__.py` (this must be done *after* creating the blueprint in `__init__.py`, in order to avoid circular imports).